# Show that: $\int_{\Omega} X d\mu = 0 \iff \mu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(w)>0\})=0$

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assignment:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ a non-negative $\mathfrak{A}$-$\bar{\mathfrak{B}}$-measurable function. 
>   Show that:
>   $$\int_{\Omega} X d\mu = 0 \iff \mu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(w)>0\})=0$$

This should be a simple proof (I believe), but I'm struggling. My approach (using non-negativeness of $X$ and a disjunct partition):
$$0 = \int_{\Omega} X d\mu = \int_{\{\omega\in\Omega: \ X(\omega) >0\}\uplus \{\omega\in\Omega: \ X(\omega) ≤ 0\}}X d\mu=\int_{X(\omega) > 0}X d\mu + \int_{X(\omega) ≤ 0}X d\mu = \int_{X(\omega)>0} Xd\mu = \int X \cdot \chi_{X(\omega)>0} d\mu$$ 
But the right-hand side of what I need to show is:
$$\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(w)>0\}) =\int\chi_{X(\omega)>0} \neq  \int X \cdot \chi_{X(\omega)>0} d\mu$$

So I'm (a) wondering where my mistake is and (b) what an alternative (better) approach would be (e.g. one where I actually so both implications separately and not simultaneously like I am trying to).

Comment: $X$ is non negative, so you don't have to consider $X(\omega)<0$. Otherwise I think there is no problem. But this approach, at this point, does not give you anything really interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\Leftarrow$" is easy. For "$\Rightarrow$", assume the contrary. Since

$$\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\frac{1}{n}\}$$

Then there is at least one $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.

$$\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\frac{1}{N}\})>0$$

Then conclude that

$$\int_\Omega Xd\mu\geq\int_{\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\frac{1}{N}\}}Xd\mu>\int_{\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\frac{1}{N}\}}\frac{1}{N}d\mu=\frac{1}{N}\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\frac{1}{N}\})>0$$

which is a contradiction

Comment: About the easy implication. For "$\Leftarrow$". We have: $\int_{\Omega}X d\mu = \int_{(\omega)>0}X d\mu = \int X\cdot\chi_{(\omega)>0}$ How do you easily isolate the integrand in order to use the assumption? Because I would write $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\ X_n\cdot\chi_{X(\omega)>0} = \lim \int \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\chi_{A_i}\cdot\chi_{X(\omega)>0} ≤ \lim \sum_{i=1}^{n}\cdot\mu(X(\omega)>0) = 0$.

Comment: Since $\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>0\})=0$, then we have $$\begin{aligned}\int_\Omega Xd\mu&=\int_{\Omega\setminus\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>0\}}Xd\mu\\&=\int_{X(\omega)=0}Xd\mu=0\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The idea is that the integral does not change if you remove a set of measure zero

Comment: Pff, of course it doesn't... Thanks for your help.

Comment: You‘re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

*Motto: Compare expectations...* Since $X\geqslant0$ almost surely, $nX\geqslant\mathbf 1_{nX\geqslant1}$ almost surely, hence $$0=n\int_\Omega X\mathrm d\mu=\int_\Omega nX\mathrm d\mu\geqslant\mu(nX\geqslant1)\geqslant0,$$ thus, $$\mu(nX\geqslant1)=0.$$
To conclude, note that $$\mu(X\gt0)=\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}\mu(nX\geqslant1).$$